# I just upgrade to Lunar Lobster and I have been encountering kernel errors?

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

Errors were encoun
tered while processing:
linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic
linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-generic
linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
I upgraded with 6.2.20 and the system would not boot so I used an older kernel 6.0.9 and I was able to startup. Then installed 6.2.12 thinking that a new kernel would help but I have the same issue system wont boot with newer kernels. Tried to remove 6.2.0.20 and it said it had dependencies. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic is not an officially supported kernel. It looks like one of the mainline kernel team "PPA" packages from here. https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2.12/ - these are not supported in any way. I would recommend you use a stock kernel, supplied by the Ubuntu project repository. Please paste the output of `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install linux-image-generic` in the question

Comment: ok her is output

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove both newer kernels by
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-6.2.12-060212-generic
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic
then
apt-get auto-remove
Seems to be working now with Kernel 6.0.9. Thanks